# draw arrow helper along THREE.Line or two vectors

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to draw arrow helper, with two vectors (x1,y1,z1)(x2,y2,z2), please give your suggestion and guidance on it..
[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: i believe this will help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128480/vector-direction-given-the-points

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can get the direction from the 2 vectors like this and create the arrow helper

```
var from = new THREE.Vector3( 2, 2, 2 );
var to = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
var direction = to.clone().sub(from);
var length = direction.length();
var arrowHelper = new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction.normalize(), from, length, 0xff0000 );
scene.add( arrowHelper );
```

Js fiddle working
http://jsfiddle.net/pardo/bgyem42v/3/